# Could someone improve kernel upgrade scripts with VirtualBox install?

Tags: updates, kernel, virtualbox

Ubuntu kernel updates are very frequent. Each time kernel is updated I need install kernel-headers and do /etc/init.d/vboxdrv setup

¿Could kernel update script check if is needed and do it properly?

I suppose that I could do it but I don't known where should be the correct place to post it and also if there is some major cause due it hasn't done yet.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `dkms` package and it will handle it for you on every kernel upgrade.

After installing DKMS, re-run the original installer for the VirtualBox Guest tools, then it will install a DKMS hook to recompile the kernel modules on every install.

To check the current status of the kernel modules, run

```
dkms status
```

Which will output e.g.:

```
vboxguest, 4.2.6, 3.2.0-43-generic, x86_64: installed
vboxguest, 4.2.6, 3.2.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed
```

---

Full steps towards a "proper" VirtualBox Guest tools installation:

1. Do a full software update of your machine *and reboot afterwards*.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```
2. Install the dependencies (compiler, Linux headers, DKMS)

   ```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers dkms
   ```
3. Run the VirtualBox Guest additions installer (from the virtual media inserted):

   ```
   sudo ./VBoxLinuxAdditions.run
   ```
4. Reboot.

Comment: I have dkms and system it's at also updated. Only need I to reinstall VirtualBox? Dkms shows: status
vboxhost, 4.2.12, 3.8.0-21-generic, x86_64: installed

Comment: @DoNoBaN No, sorry, but I assumed you were talking about the guest tools, but your output shows you're running the host kernel modules. In your case, all looks fine (as long as you're talking about the host and not the guest) and there's no indication something's wrong. Why do you think something is wrong?